# Wordpress: How to add comment for taxonomy page

Tags: wordpress, comments, taxonomy

I need to add comments for taxonomy page. I would like to know if it is possible.

Thanks for help.

Michal

Answer (score -2):

It's definitly possible :) Just put `<?php comments_template(); ?>` in the place you want your comments to appear.

If you haven't already, create a template for your taxonomy archive (just copy the contents of archive.php), and call it `taxonomy-{taxonomy_slugname}.php` or `taxonomy.php`. This is where you put `<?php comments_template(); ?>`.

Comment: It's not that simple, comments need a post parent, default tax pages are not connected with a post object

Comment: Sorry about that, should've known.. Anyway, op might be able to achieve what he's looking for by creating a page instead. Pull content from the taxonomy he wants through a plugin like this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-post-shortcode/

Comment: The problem is that I need to use taxonomy page. So If I understand it is not possible, is that right? Or someone know way how to do it? Thanks for help.